# PHP DomElement select child html tags without parent tag

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to get contents of DOM element like JS function innerHTML does.
Currently i do it like this is there shorter way of doing it without loop?
if i use ->nodeValue it will do what i need but it strips HTML tags.

Basically i need to get all children of dom element including their tags with one command.

```
$html= "<div>
           <p>One</p>
           <p>Two</p>
       </div>";



$dom_doc = new DOMDocument();
@$dom_doc->loadHTML($html);

$html_elements = $dom_doc->getElementsByTagName("div");



//vvar_dump($dom_doc->saveHTML($html_elements->item(0)));
//this will return "<div><p>One</p><p>Two</p></div>" and i only need contents of div tag

//vvar_dump($html_elements->item(0)->nodeValue;
//this will return "OneTwo" without <p> tags

$innerHTML = "";

$child_elements = $html_elements->item(0)->childNodes;

foreach($child_elements as $key) {
     $innerHTML .= $html_elements->item(0)->childNodes->item($key);
}


vvar_dump($innerHTML);


//returns: <p>One</p><p>Two</p>
```